# How use class methods in jQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, function

I want to make  automate color parent changer in my js.

here is my html :

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="target" >
        traget
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my js :

```
function ColorBox(target_id, btn) {

    this.parent = $("#" + target_id).parent();

    this.color = $(this.parent).append('<div class="color" >ops</div>');
    $(this.color).append('<button class="change" value="' + btn + '">' + btn + '</button>');

    this.ChangeColor = function (elm_id) {
        $(this.parent).css('background', $(elm_id).val());
        return true;
    }
    // here my problem start
    $("#" + $(this.parent).attr('id') + " .change").bind('click', function () {
        // how I can do it in here.
        ColorBox.ChangeColor($(this));
    });

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ColorBox('target', 'red');
});
```

I add some element to target parent and I want when clicked on `change` class the `ColorBox.ChangeColor` execute and but in bind method I can't use `this.ChangeColor`.

Now how I can do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try keeping the function's scope separate by assigning `this` to a variable (e.g. `self`). This will avoid any issues with accessing function variables and functions inside different scopes.

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/37zq5/10/

Here you can see the code changes I made:

```
function ColorBox(target_id, btn) {

    var self = this;

    self.parent = $("#" + target_id).parent();
    self.color = self.parent.append('<div class="color" >ops</div>');
    self.color.append('<button class="change" value="' + btn + '">' + btn + '</button>');

    $("#" + self.parent[0].id + " .change").on('click', function () {
        self.parent.css('background', this.value);
    });

};

$(document).ready(function () {
    new ColorBox('target', 'red');
    new ColorBox('target2','lime');
});
```

Comment: Instead of `self` I often see `that` used. It's just important to keep it consistent.

Comment: @k0pernikus - you're correct, you can assign it to whatever you're comfortable with. Personally, I prefer `self` but `that` is just as valid.

Comment: This have one problem if I use in two element don't answer or example : `ColorBox('target','red') ; ColorBox('target2','lime') ;`  it is do on second only.

Comment: @MahdiParsa - remember to use `new`, here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/37zq5/7/

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would probably do it this way. It's a bit of a different approach; you don't need `this`, you don't need `new`, and it's less code:

```
function ColorBox(target_id, btn) {
    var $parent = $("#" + target_id).parent();
    var $color = $('<div class="color">ops</div>').appendTo($parent);
    var $button = $('<button class="change" value="' + btn + '">' +
            btn + '</button>').appendTo($color);

    $button.on( 'click', function (event) {
        $parent.css('background', $button.val());
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ColorBox('target', 'red');
});
```

Whether you take this approach or do something more like @Joe's answer, there is one thing you should definitely change to work like I have it in this code. Your `parent` and `color` variables are both already jQuery objects; there is no need to wrap them in additional `$()` calls when you use them. So change the names of these variables to include the `$` prefix as a reminder that they are jQuery objects, and then just use them directly where you need them instead of the extra `$()` wrapper.

If you use `self` as in @Joe's answer, then it would be code like:

```
self.$parent = $("#" + target_id).parent();
self.$color = self.$parent.append(...);
```

The `$` prefix on these names isn't necessary, but it's a common convention to indicate a variable or property that is a jQuery object. It helps keep straight whether you need to use another `$()` around it.

Also, be aware that your `parent` and `color` variables are the same element. It looks like you're expecting `color` to be the `<color>` element, but it isn't. I changed the code so it is the `<color>` element.

Comment: Thanks for your guide. your answer have good notes for me . :)

Comment: Glad to help. That's why it's great to get answers from more than one person; each one has something different to contribute to the conversation. Keep up the good work!